# Organize Product List By Categories

Tags: sorting, magento, collections

I was wondering, for those of you who are Magento developers, what do you think is the wisest way to approach filtering out a product collection product list where you organize the results by sorting through categories?

For instance, imagine you sell bicycles and accessories. You would have 3 categories when people search **bicycle**:

```
1.) Bicycles (Category ID #3)
2.) Bicycle Helmet (Category ID #4)
3.) Bicycle Accessory - Water Bottles (Category ID #10)
```

If I were to have a custom controller and create my own collection, and I wanted to sort products where the category ID #3 products are listed first, then category ID #4 and then category ID #5.

Whether this appears in a search result page or just a 'shop all products' page, the same question applies - should I be finding a way to sort by category and, if so, what is the best way to do this? When I look at the methods to work with a product controller function, I am not sure which would allow me to say "Show this category first, then this category, and then that category"

Logically, what is the best way to handle this request?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try with the `Category Filter` ?

It's a part of the layered navigation and it's available on all product list (even catalog_search)

To can activate it, just put the `is_anchor` param of a category to `True` (in the `Display Settings` tab).

With that, in the left column of your product list, you'll see that you can filter you're product list by category (one by one only, no multi selection)

You can see an example here : http://demo.magentocommerce.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=and

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately, this is a custom request from a client and requires a specific product result page to have a collection where it knows "I will take all of these products and sort them by this category id first, then load products in this collection from that category and, when done, sort the rest of the products by that category.

So it must know what category id's to filter through and order them that way. I thought I found a solution but it does not work on 1.7+ 

http://blog.chapagain.com.np/Magento-how-to-filter-product-collection-using-2-or-more-category-filters/